¿Funcionamiento de los Observables en Angular 18?
estoy aprendiendo un poco de Angular 18, estoy conectando la aplicación a un pequeño proyecto de Spring. Mi duda surge de que estoy utilizando un HttpClient para traer una lista de entidades del proyecto de Spring.
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { TrainingUnit } from "../models/training-unit";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class TrainingUnitsService {
  private url: string = "http://localhost:9090/gimnasios";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAllTrainingUnits(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<TrainingUnit[]>(this.url);
  }
}

Dentro de la clase de mi componente, donde utilizo el service, tengo esta lógica para guardar los elementos de la lista recuperada en un array de Typescript:
export class UnitsComponent {
  arrayComplete: boolean = false;
  array: TrainingUnit[] = [];

  constructor(private service: TrainingUnitsService) {
    this.getTrainigUnits();
  }

  getTrainigUnits(): TrainingUnit[] {
    this.array = [];
    this.service.getAllTrainingUnits().subscribe((units) => {
      for (var unit of units) {
        this.array.push(
          new TrainingUnit(
            unit.name,
            new TrainingUnitAddress(
              unit.idTrainingUnitAddress.name,
              unit.idTrainingUnitAddress.outerNumber,
              unit.idTrainingUnitAddress.insideNumber,
              unit.idTrainingUnitAddress.state,
              unit.idTrainingUnitAddress.city
            )
          )
        );
      }
      this.arrayComplete = true;
    });
    return this.array;
  }
}

Y muestro cada información de cada objeto de la variable array en el template con un for y gracias a la bandera booleana arrayComplete
@if (this.arrayComplete) {
  @for (unit of this.array; track unit.name) {
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="foto-descriptiva">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title"> {{ unit.name }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text"> {{ unit.trainingUnitAddress.fullAddress() }} </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> Botón de Inscripción </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}

Mi pregunta es que, de no utilizar la bandera booleana arrayComplete, cuando se ha llenado la variable array con los datos obtenidos del backend gracias al observable, se genera un error e investigando, entendí que la secuencia del método getTrainigUnits() en la clase del componente retorna la variable array vacía antes de que la lógica de subscripción del Observable llene la variable array. Existe alguna otra manera de evitar este error o cual sería una mejor manera de tratar esto? Un saludo**

Qué error? No tiene sentido que se genere un error si pintas algo con un ngFor (o un @for ahora), porque esos bucles iteran sobre los elementos del array... si es un array vacío, no hay elementos con lo cual no se genera html, simple. Define por favor qué error te daba. Llevo años trabajando con angular y jamás he usado un flag para determinar si el array está completo o no... también te digo, que jamás recorro arrays con bucles "a mano"... para eso tienes el método .map, además usando observables puedes mutarlos .pipe(map(in -> {})) o usando flatMap si trabajas con colecciones

Si vas a usar observables, te recomiendo que aprendas a trabajar con ellos en vez de intentar hacerlo todo "a mano", te hará la vida mucho más sencilla.

No sé si afecta, pero en los templates no necesitas poner this para referirte a los atributos del componente. Creo que tu componente podría escribirse así:
export class UnitsComponent {
  arrayComplete: boolean = false;
  array: TrainingUnit[] = [];

  constructor(private service: TrainingUnitsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTrainigUnits();
  }
  
  getTrainigUnits() {
    
    this.service.getAllTrainingUnits().subscribe(units => {
      this.array = units.map( unit => 
          new TrainingUnit(
            unit.name,
            new TrainingUnitAddress(
              unit.idTrainingUnitAddress.name,
              unit.idTrainingUnitAddress.outerNumber,
              unit.idTrainingUnitAddress.insideNumber,
              unit.idTrainingUnitAddress.state,
              unit.idTrainingUnitAddress.city
            )
          )
      );  
    });
  }
}

El método getTrainingUnits no necesita devolver nada, todo se queda en el atributo array.
Y el template podría ser algo como:
@for (unit of array; track unit.name) {
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="foto-descriptiva">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title"> {{ unit.name }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text"> {{ unit.trainingUnitAddress.fullAddress() }} </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> Botón de Inscripción </a>
      </div>
    </div>
}

Ya que el bucle sólo se ejecuta si el array no está vacío.

Muchas gracias por la recomendación. Suelo colocarle this por la costubre más que nada. Saludos
